# Why do I suddenly get a blank screen with Rails on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have combed through lots of references to this issue (most recently followed tips on  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36482802/5965865), but nothing helped.

Here's the issue: I already have a Rails app that works-or used to work on localhost:3000. But then, suddenly I get blank screens with the same app. The app works with no problem in `rails console`. The default Rails screen shows up too. The more I read abut blank screens, the more I am lost.

So the sequence of events--all potentially could be complicating factors:

- I run the Rails via CLI.
- I also have MAMP installed to work with a WordPress site locally.
- At one point, either before MAMP or after MAMP, I installed Brew. (All were done following online instructions.)

Not long ago, I tested out a simple Rails app on Heroku, which at first worked, but then the app no longer could be updated. After much tinkering, I removed rbenv and the problem went away (ie my Rails app could be updated on Heroku again).

All of these issues seem to be related. But are they? How do I find out?

- Rails 5.2.1
- Ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by suddenly went blank? Look for before/after steps you took. Also, check the Rails logs to see what's wrong. This might also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476142/888278

Comment: What I meant was: I'd get a white screen with nothing on it when I should have gotten a page with content. I had seen the posted you suggested and actually posted a question there because I found the `pids` folder  (in `tmp/pids`), but it's empty (no file named `server.pid` -in fact, no file at all.) Not sure what it means.

Comment: Also: Since the first time I got a white screen on `localhost:3000`, I haven't been able to see anything (except for the welcome page of rails). Not sure what led to the first white/blank screen.

Comment: The default welcome page has always been available, just not the other pages. I have just removed rvm and now rails won't run b/c it can't find `gem railties`. So I am trying to see which tip to follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212116/rails-could-not-find-railties).

Comment: I am trying to understand the relationship btw rvm and Brew and MAMP. When I did `which rails`, the path is `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/rails` The three somehow doesn't seem to get along.

Comment: I strongly suggest looking at logs. That'll make it clear what's exactly going on wrong.